# Install rails from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed ruby and next rails as a gem with this command

```
gem install rails -include-dependencies
```

It installed successfully but even after restarting my command window i couldnt run commands like:

```
rails
```

or

```
rails s
```

My question is what do i have to add to my path so that rails is recognized in my command windwo?

----Update----

I ran gem list but rails isnt listed,
so i will reune the gem install rails command

Comment: What OS do you use, what output of `rails` command, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **rvm** you need to use the ***gemset*** of RVM in which you have installed your *rails* gem.

cmd for the same is

> rvm gemset list

will list the gemset persent in your version manager, later select the gemset with following command:

> rvm gemset use [gemset_name]

hope am redirecting you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a project with:

`rails new whatever`

Go into the project:

`cd whatever`

Install dependencies:

`bundle install`

Start server:

`rails s`

Comment: This may not work when he does not even get the `rails` command, as I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a unix based OS, you may need to get the path of the rails executable into your `$PATH` e.g. by e.g. `exec $SHELL -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if you know about this already, but why don't you use a pre-packaged installer like [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rbenv?

If so, try running this in your terminal:

`rbenv rehash`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using windows, you might not have added Ruby's bin directory in path :

To add path in windows :

Right click `My Computer` >> `properties` >> `Adavced System Settings`

Then edit the `path` variable in `User Variable` and just add the path of your installed Ruby's bin directory.

Open a new command prompt to get the path changes.